# ALSA async callbacks?

Tags: linux, audio, asynchronous, callback, alsa

The ALSA documentation seems to be very lacking... Basically, I need to play sounds asynchronously, be able to stop (all) sounds, and get a callback when one has finished playing successfully.

I can mostly do the first 2, its just the latter I'm having trouble with.

Does anyone know any snippets that may enlighten me?

Further Details:

Basically the user will be browsing a collection of sounds, when they hover over one, it should play it, and when they go onto the next one, that one should stop very quickly, and the next should play etc.... This will happen fast. The last one they heard in its entirety should be selected (hence why I need the callback if a whole sound plays successfully, as atm the one selected isn't necessarily the one they least heard, due to threading)

I don't really want to use any libraries other than libasound.